# Where is the gmapping.cpp located in an installation from deb packages?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i have a relatively noobish question.

I want to change some things in the [gmapping.cpp](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/melodic-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp)  file so i can get the probabilistic values of the OGM but i cant locate the file in my machine.I installed Ros through Debian packages. The thing is that I am using gmapping and i don't understand where the file could be located. I searched in the /opt/ros/melodic/share-inc-lib and i couldn't find a file that handles the change from the probabilistic values to the standard ones.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388178/where-is-the-gmapping.cpp-located-in-an-installation-from-deb-packages?/) by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its compiled code, it doesn't exist in the debians. You will need to build gmapping from source and make your modifications in a workspace.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1